# Scala - Extract a list efficiently from a map

Tags: scala, refactoring, nested-lists

I have a large json object: myNestedObject

```
{
    "size": 2,
    "values": [{
        "name": "mullock",
        "upstatus": "Green",
        "details": {
            "key": "rupture farms",
            "server": "mudos",
            "owner": "magog_cartel",
            "type": "NORMAL",
            "links": {
                "self": [{
                    "address": "https://mudos.com:port/access"
                }]
            }
        }
    },{
        "name": "tassadar",
        "upstatus": "Orange",
        "details": {
            "key": "archon",
            "server": "protoss",
            "owner": "aspp67",
            "type": "NORMAL",
            "links": {
                "self": [{
                    "address": "https://aiur.com:port/access"
                }]
            }
        }
    }],
    "limit": 100
}
```

This is what the case classes look like as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class Result(size: Int, limit: Int, values: Seq[Values])
case class Values(name: String, upstatus: String, details: ValuesDetails)
case class ValuesDetails(key: String, server: String, owner: String, `type`: String, links: ValuesDetailsLinks)
case class ValuesDetailsLinks(self: Seq[ValuesDetailsLinksAddress])
case class ValuesDetailsLinksAddress(address: String)

object Foo {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper 
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    def test(Json): Unit
        val return = mapper.readValue[Result](Json)
```

> myNestedObject.size

is a field that gives the length of the array

> myNestedObject.values(i)

Trying to extract the below values into a List[String]

> myNestedObject.values(i).name

I've been using a crude for loop to extract and the code works.

```
 val selectNames: List[String] = (
    for (i <- 0 to myNestedObject.size-1 toList) yield
        myNestedObject.values(i).name
)
```

Refactoring my code and trying to use a .map (unsuccessfully) to do the same thing, two attempts:

```
myNestedObject.map(_ => values(i).name) 

myNestedObject.(values(i).name).asInstanceOfList
```

Disclaimer: I'm a complete novice at this.

SOLUTION: the values list can be accessed without specifying index

```
myNestedObject.values.map(_.name)
```

Comment: What is the static type of `myNestedObject.values(i)`? What are the specific error messages you are encoutering with you current refactoring attempts?

Comment: What kind of efficiency you are looking for the time or space?

Comment: @oowekyala Added a sample Json into the question.  The first gives error "value map is not a member of result".  myNestedObject is of type result which I defined as the structure.  also added this to the question

Comment: @RamanMishra Time Efficiency

Comment: Is this Jason coming from  some rest end point? And r u converting it into the case class? Using spray json library or you are just processing over json?

Comment: @RamanMishra Yes It's from some restAPI I can't change the layout of. 
 Using the jacksonlibrary I've included code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do this:

```
myNestedObject.values.map(_.name)
```

Comment: @CormacRogers, no problem... Scala is a rich language that can take a long time to learn (at least it did for me!)

Answer (score 1):

Dylan Grald's answer is correct, but you could also use an equivalent for-comprehension

```
for (x <- myNestedObject.values)
  yield (x.name)
```

This desugars to the version using the `map` method.  For simple cases like this I prefer just calling the `map` method directly, but I thought I would mention the `for` version as an alternative.